# Topics design : Oracle database tables to Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Our requirement is to fetch the data from oracle database tables and publish to Kafka topics using JDBC source connectors. We have around 300 tables and we are looking to create 300 topics. One topic for each table. Is it good to have 300 connectors configuration running in Connect Cluster or is there any connector config we can distribute the 10 tables data to one topic for example using the JDBC connector?.

We are using the Confluent Kafka on cloud. The message format we plan to use Avro

Comment: I think Kafka JDBC source connector allow you to copy multiple database tables to multiple topics by configuring table.whitelist:

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html